# Automatically reduce size of images in phpfox

Tags: php, image

I am currently using phpfox neutron pro (V4.5) software, I am encountering problems with uploading images/photos.

Whenever I upload an image, the software does not reduce the size of the image, it uploads the image as it is. Assuming you are uploading 1 GB sized image, phpfox allows it to be uploaded as that size.

Is there a way to let the software reduce or compress the image during upload, this feature can be observed in Facebook.com.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

PHPfox support this feature :

Users >> Manage User Groups. Select Default User Groups that you want. For Registered User >> Manage User Settings >> Photo .

change size there .

but if you want to change it programmatically resize a image in php use this function :

```
function resize_image($file, $w, $h, $crop=FALSE) {
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
    $r = $width / $height;
    if ($crop) {
        if ($width > $height) {
            $width = ceil($width-($width*abs($r-$w/$h)));
        } else {
            $height = ceil($height-($height*abs($r-$w/$h)));
        }
        $newwidth = $w;
        $newheight = $h;
    } else {
        if ($w/$h > $r) {
            $newwidth = $h*$r;
            $newheight = $h;
        } else {
            $newheight = $w/$r;
            $newwidth = $w;
        }
    }
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

    return $dst;
}
```

you can call this function by adding this bellow code in your project :

```
$img = resize_image(‘/path/to/some/image.jpg’, 200, 200);
```

Comment: With that feature in PHPFox, it restricts the user to upload up to a certain limit of image size but doesn't not compress the image when a larger file is uploaded

Comment: You can add this function to php fox file uploader and call it in image uploader .

Comment: Please where can the file uploader be found in the files